# Grab number from a div and populate select drop down with the same amount of options

Tags: jquery, forms, drop-down-menu

I am trying to populate a select drop down with the same amount of options as a number in a separate div.

For example, if a div has a value of "3" in it, i need to populate the select drop down with 3 options.... e.g.:

```
<select name="quantity">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

If the number in the div is changed to 6 - then it will populate the select with 6 options.

Any help much appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: Can we see the *'trying'* code please?

Comment: Where does the `name` come from? What's the connection between the `select` and the `div`?

Comment: How the div is getting changed?

Comment: How are you changing the content of a div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[http://jsfiddle.net/Sgqjg/](http://jsfiddle.net/Sgqjg/1/)

the html is:

```
<div id="changeMe">9</div>

<select name="quantity" id="populateMe">
</select>
```

and the script is:

```
var num = parseInt($("#changeMe").text());
var opt = '';
for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
     opt +=  "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
}
$("#populateMe").html(opt);
```

Edit: *appending and converting to int the text value of the div in each loop slows the proccess.*

Comment: It will be slower to append each option this way than to store it in a variable and append the variable once in the end

Answer (score 0):

Call this code whenever your div is changed. Assuming the id of your div is 'otherDiv' and the id of your dropdown is 'yourSelect'

```
var count = parseInt ( $("#otherDiv").html() );

var options = "";
for (var x = 1; x<= count; x++)
{ 
   options += "<option>" + x + "</option>";
}

$("#yourSelect").htmml(options);
```

(This requires jquery)

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
var $sel = $("select");

$("input").keyup(function () {
    $sel.empty();
    var howMany = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    for (var i = 1; i <= howMany; i++) {
        $sel.append("<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>");
    }
});​
```

Highly polished layout:

```
<select></select>
<input />
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/SSQRs/2/)

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the input - all of the methods worked but chose the top answer as it allowed the options to be populated based on a div content, not on change of an input.